# Looking for a good datagrid plug-in for jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a requirement to let my users maintain some accounts and accommodations. Each account can 1 to many accommodations and each accommodation is link to only 1 account.

I want to be able to let the users edit the account details. On the same page I would like to list the accommodations that are linked to that account and allow the user to link more accommodations to that account, double click on an accommodation to edit its details and to also be able to delink the accommodation.

I thought that is really suited to having a datagrid for the accommodations as well as maybe a lookup field to add more accommodations to the datagrid. Can anyone recommend a jQuery datagrid?

EDIT:
Been looking around and found the following.

- jqGrid
- FlexiGrid
- ingrid

so far my favourite looks like jqGrid

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Grid Recommendations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using jqGrid now. I like it more than Flexigrid for the following reasons:

- Supports [trees, sub-grids, and other drill down features](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)
- Many options for in-row and pop-up form editing.
- Several themes to choose from, with [support for jQuery UI themes](http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid35/jqgrid.html) coming RSN.
- There is actual [documentation](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm)
- It has been very easy for me to customize to do things that neither grid does "out-of-the-box"

Update: I wrote [a short article on its advantages and disadvantages in more detail](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/14/38200/), but with an ASP.NET MVC focus.

Answer (score 5):

[Flexigrid](http://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/) is the best one. Highly recommend.

Here is the -> [SAMPLE](http://www.sanderkorvemaker.nl/test/flexigrid/)

Another alternative is [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). And here is the -> [DEMO](http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). There are more interesting features. But it looks ugly in my opinion.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this even existed for jQuery. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

The below Jquery grid is awesome is sense that , you dont have to create add, edit forms , for
the fields defined in grid .

http://www.jtable.org/

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a note, try http://www.jqwidgets.com/, they have very good controls too.