# Which datagrid plugin should I use when table row count is in thousands

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jqgrid, flexigrid

Which datagrid plugin should I use when table **row count** is in **thousands**.

I am currently using flexigrid but it gets unresponsive when all the rows are displayed in GUI.
We got some 10K lines of code most of which is closely coupled with flexigrid features.
Any plugin which has good responsiveness as well as which can be incorporated with minimal code changes is highly preferred.

PS: Don't suggest pagination. My Application requirement demands for all data to be loaded at once as it is hierarchical data.
I have already gone through these links. [Choosing a jQuery datagrid plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622716/choosing-a-jquery-datagrid-plugin),  [Looking for a good datagrid plug-in for jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685664/looking-for-a-good-datagrid-plug-in-for-jquery), [Best dynamic JavaScript/JQuery Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677298/best-dynamic-javascript-jquery-grid)

Comment: I have had the same issues (between 50k and 750k lines in return). After messing around with some generic plugins, I have decided the easiest way is just to make an own plugin for my special needs. General plugins that you download have the problem that they cover the basic needs of the broad masses, but not your special one.

Comment: I still question the notion that a user can effectively work with thousands of rows at a time. Do your users really enjoy that aspect of your application? Does sort/filter make it manageable? And then you have the performance implications of querying and displaying that much data at a time.

Comment: @JustinEthier I agreed with your suggestion but User requirement forces to design application in such a way that it requires all data at once as data is in hierarchical form.